# How do I perform cascading deletes with EF4?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

On a previous project we had EF4 performing cascading deletes (Delete a parent record and the child records are deleted, too). On this project (different company), EF4 is not performing cascading deletes. What do I need to do to make EF4 perform a cascading delete?

Comment: Perhaps I don't fully understand the issue, but aren't cascading deletes performed by the database? How would this become an EF issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using just EF4's cascading delete is not enough; you should set up cascading deletes on your database as well, in case not all children are loaded into the object context.  That being said, the cascade delete properties are set on the assocation.  Go to the model browser, select an assocation and view properties.

Comment: According to the architect, we are not and will not be setting up cascading deletes on the database. I'll look at the association properties. Thanks!

Comment: @Special It's your party :) You can set it in either direction; check the OnDelete properties.

Comment: MorganPDX is right about not doing it in just one place. If you set it up in the EDM, you have to pay very careful attention for cases where it's possible that not all related data is loaded into memory. If there are more "children" in the database and you dn't have the cascade there as well, you will get an exception when the db attempts to delete the "parent".  Just sayin....it's a recommendation from the EF team as well.

Answer (score 0):

I am on the same boat. I only have cascade on delete in EDM/EF4 and not (yet) in the database. Try this...

In the relationship, set the OnDelete of parent's end (1 multiplicity) to Cascade . Then in your code load all children before saving the changes (deletion).

```
var parent = context.Parents.SingleOrDefault(p => p.Id == parentId);
parent.Children.Load();
if (parent != null)
        {
            context.Parent.DeleteObject(parent);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two ways of cascade deleting implementation:

1. Set up it on the database layer (triggers or relationships)
2. Try to use extension methods. You can define delete logic for current table and call methods for related table updating.